# Write a file and check if a file exists

Tags: javascript, file, html

I would like to write a `.txt` file to a local disk (and prompt the user to scan a document) after which the script should halt/loop until it finds a certain `.pdf` file on the local disc.

EDIT:

I have heard that HTML5 packs a new JavaScript API called "FILE API", and I KNOW that what I'm trying to do IS possible. I just have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The first Google hit for [HTML5 file API](http://www.google.com/search?q=html5+file+api) is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications which explains the capabilities and limitations. In short, it's only for reading files uploaded by the user.

Comment: @TJHeuvel Obivously, but what I am asking is what to write. You are so smart.

Answer (score 0):

It s not possible to access to the local drive via the browser / javascript